# ExpressionEngine issue with Wygwam

Tags: ckeditor, expressionengine

I have this posted here:
https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/wygwam_not_styled_in_cp_entry_and_not_functioning_shown_errors_attached

...but I really need a fix asap if anyone can help here.

I can't get Wygwam to work.

It started with me running this:

- EE 1.6.8 (Again, can't update)
- Wygwam 2.1.6
- FieldFrames 1.4.5

I wasn't able to activate the module. I would receive errors and then the field was jacked.

I then upgraded Wygwam to 2.6.3 and that allowed my to enable the module.

The problem I have now is this:

When I try to Add a new Wygwam field, it tells me that there are no configurations available. When I go to 'Edit Configurations', I only get the serial number input field. I added the serial number, but nothing changed. Under 'Editor Configurations' it just says: There are currently no configurations.

Now I have the existing fields back, however, I cannot view source and do not have any "Configurable Editors" available. I also cannot setup any "Configurable Editors" in the module because I have no settings/options display. Also, I cannot add any new Wygwam fields because when I do, I just get a white screen.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the fieldtype and Wygwam module then reinstalling?

Comment: I would, but I would lose all of their entry data that way wouldn't I? there are hundreds upon hundreds.

Comment: Brian,
you might lose the data, but I don't think so. In any case backing up the database before doing the uninstall would protect you in case of data loss.

Comment: If you change the Wygwam field to an EE textarea field before you uninstall Wygwam you will not lose anything.

Comment: I agree with Alex, but absolutely backup so you can restore if needed. I would uninstall, delete theme and module files from server, check DB for any leftover WYGWAM rows (check module and extension tables). Also, check for any custom WYGWAM tables (I can't remember if it creates one.) Then upload new files, install and reassign your fields to WYGWAM. Should do the trick.

Comment: Guys, thanks for the input. Unfortunately, this was on a messy MSM install that has been abused. Also, I don't have direct access to the DB, etc. It's all handled through a request process, sometimes by which time it gets done, the backup keeps a days worth of changes, which can be a ton, out of the picture. Hopefully this gives better reason to upgrade/rebuild sooner rather than later.   ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, While this may not be the best answer to provide, it has provided a resolve to the situation I was in.

First off, Kudos goes to Brad Bell at Pixel & Tonic for sticking with me via emails in trying to get this fixed. I am in a situation with this site in which I can't provide access to the site, files, data, etc. It definitely makes getting help with EE related instances more difficult. Brandon and his staff definitely know how to push through these issues.

Thanks guys.

Nothing we were trying was working. What I had to end up doing was rolling back the versions of Wygwam and Matrix from the more recent releases that were installed to WW 2.1.1 and Matrix 2.0.11

I didn't try newer versions as I want to push harder than ever now for a site update/rebuild due to these issues and others. The site is again functional in these areas and they can move forward, (or laterally... depending on your stance), again.